# Function to automatize file import

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function to more or less automatize file import for experimental data.So far it works fine if the folder only contains one file, but the program I use creates two files in the given file path for e.g. Trial1: 
`Trial1_001_match_20161115_121628.csv.aborted` and `Trial1_001_midi_20161115_121628.csv.aborted`. I'm only interested in the midi file. Is there an easy way to implement that only the file containing the string `midi` gets imported or something like this?

```
 path <- "C:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/tapping backup/Pilot141116/pilot_151116_pat1_250/realisations/participant_8/Trial1"

setwd( path )
files <- list.files(path = path, pattern = ".csv", full.names = T )

# set up a function to read a file and add a column for filename
import <- function( file ) {
  df <- read_csv( file, col_names = T )
  df$file <- file
  return( df )
}

# run that function across all files.
data1 <- ldply( .data = files, .fun = import )`
```

Comment: In your `list.files` call use `"midi.*\\.csv"` as pattern. Pattern excepts regular expressions, so you can finetune with it which files you want to list

Answer (score 1):

As you don't giva a reproducible example, I can't check, but the following should work: `files[grepl("midi", files)]`.